# Set initial queue lenght in AnyLogic Discrete Event Simulation

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to simulate a manufacturing process in AnyLogic with the Discrete Event Simulation.
I am using the Queue block as a means to model a warehouse.
My question is: is it possible to set the initial length of the queue? For instance, I would like my process to have in "Warehouse 1" 100 pieces at the very right moment when the simulation starts.
Is it possible to do so?
Thank you

EDIT: The answer from Felipe solved my problem.

Comment: connect a source to the queue that generates 100 agents in the beginning of the simulation

Comment: Good idea! Thank you!

Comment: Add it as an answer so others can benefit as well 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Felipe hereabove the simplest solution is to add a second source that, at the beginning of the simulation, inputs the agents in the system.